# Compare two arrays if a match found do something

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, associative-array

I have two arrays one is categories and another is categories_two the category array contains the whole categories from the table and the categories_two contains the categories selected(selected on adding of the item now want to use for updating)

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <?php 
     foreach ($categories as $c) {
  ?>

    <div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$c->category_id?>" name="categories[]"> <i></i> <?=$c->category_name?> </label></div>
  <?php

    }
  ?>

</div>
```

and i have the selected categories **so now i want to tick the selected categories. how to do that?**in categories_two i have the id's of categories

```
array(
          [0] => category_id;
          [1] => category_id;
          [2] => category_id;


     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array()`:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <?php 
        foreach ($categories as $c) {
    ?>

    <div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$c->category_id?>" name="categories[]" <?php if(in_array($c->category_id, $categories_two) {echo "checked"})?>> <i></i> <?=$c->category_name?> </label></div>
    <?php

        }
    ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot@Jay Patel

Comment: @Ranjith I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check existence of category in category_two. for example in your code if you want to select category that is posted, check below:-

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <?php 
     foreach ($categories as $c) {
  ?>

    <div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$c->category_id?>" name="categories[]" <?=(in_array($c->category_id, $_POST['categories']) "SELECTED" : "")?> <i></i> <?=$c->category_name?> </label></div>
  <?php

    }
  ?>

</div>
```

If you want to select for category_two then it depends on data arranged in category_two.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for two array and select the checkbox which is in the second array. you can use the following code to selected that.

```
<?php 
    foreach($category as $c){
     $selected = false; 
    foreach($category_two as $c_two){
      if($c===$c_two){
        $selected=true;
      }
    } ?>
    <div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$c->category_id?>" name="categories[]" <?php echo $selected?'checked="checked":'';?>/> <i></i> <?=$c->category_name?> </label></div>
    <?php } ?>
```